# Keycloak and Power Automate

Tags: keycloak, power-automate

I've created a keycloak client OAuth2.0, tokens are generated correctly when using Postman, which means everything is configured.

[Keycloak config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MrdTv.png)

My issue is that when I try to use exactly the same information in a custom connector i've created in Power automate:
[Power automate config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/opLYr.png)

Upon entering the user/password in a popup, I get this error:
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xv14D.png)

I already asked this question in power automate community forum, but still not having any response.